# Connecting Infusionsoft data to Google data studio

Tags: data, google, data-formats, google-data-studio

I want to create a Google Data studio dashboard from Infusion soft data.
The main problem are the connectors - there are multiple tools that provide direct connectors but they are paid solutions like Klipfolio, Clicdata, Grow etc.

If a direct connection is not possible, I want to use some combination of Google sheets and Zapier or other free tools to create a data flow that can be constantly refreshed for data coming in from "infusionsoft" to "Google data studio"

Questions summary:

1. Is there any direct way of connecting Infusionsoft data or API with Google data studio (maybe with some Database like MySQL/postgresql/cloud sql etc?)
2. What are some free mid-tier tools I can use to create this data connection?(Zapier, google sheets, excel etc)

All your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting to look at this now, to start with simply on batched/CSV export/import process pushing data into Google BigQuery first and using it as a source in DataStudio. I've thought about how to automate and I'm not sure Zapier will cut it - it doesn't seem to have an action for Contact 'updates' for one, which is a showstopper for us (though you don't mention what objects you want to query).

Another option would be to use the [Novak Solutions Data Warehouse](https://pages.novaksolutions.com/data-warehouse/) service to get everything into SQL and either query directly from DataStudio or replicate into BigQuery using [StitchData](https://www.stitchdata.com/) or similar.

If you want a cheaper option still, it could be done via the Infusionsoft API, but you'd have the time and cost of creating the synchronisation tasks and managing changes. If you have a limited subset of objects (eg. Contacts + Tags) this might be cost effective.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free, but it is the best option that I've found... MyFusionHelper will let you auto export any saved report in IFS to Google Sheets with one of its features. Then when you connect Data Studio the Google Sheet that is automatically updated... Boom... you get your reports. You can set update frequency and a lot more.

Only thing I've ever found that did this right other than programming an API connection yourself. It's not free but it's relatively inexpensive.